# how to pass html element through a javascript function as parameter

Tags: javascript, dom

I fall in trouble to pass a html element to a javascript function.

The div that I try to delete and pass to the function, that contains two things, one is `<input>` element and another one is `<p>` element.

In this case, I am try to make a todo list, where I am trying to delete something, and it should delete from there, then appeared on other div. So, I pass the nodelist(denoted as node over here) to `show_delete_items(node[i])`, I thought it will be appeared in that div, but i'ts not happening, whats wrong here, can anybody help me to elevate my wrong approach.

```
function delete_items() {
  console.log('delete items function got called!');

  let node = document.getElementsByClassName('check_box_div');
  console.log(node);
  // node
  // let n_0 = node[0].childNodes;
  // console.log(n_0[0].checked);
  // console.log(node[0].childNodes);

  for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    let ch = node[i].childNodes;
    if (ch[0].checked === true) {
      console.log('This is true and removed!', i);
      // ch.
      console.log('parent element = ', ch.parentElement);
      console.log('node = ', node[i]);
      show_delete_items(node[i]); //I try to pass this nodelist 
      /*
            when I print that node, it looks like this:    
            <div class="check_box_div" style="padding: 10px 15px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin: 10px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between;"><input type="checkbox"><p class="para"> vbcfb </p></div>
*/

      ch[0].parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
}

function show_delete_items(it) {

  if (document.getElementsByClassName('del_div').length === 0) {


    let del_div = document.createElement('div');
    del_div.className = 'del_div';
    del_div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    del_div.style.width = '400px';
    del_div.style.height = 'auto';
    del_div.style.margin = 'auto';

    let main_container = document.body;
    main_container.appendChild(del_div);
  }
  let new_div = document.createElement('div');
  new_div.className = 'inner_div';

  new_div.appendChild(it.childNodes);
  // new_div.insertAdjacentHTML(it);

  let del_div_check = document.querySelector('.del_div');
  del_div_check.appendChild(new_div);

}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Showing this error message, when I try above code.

from `show_delete_item` function:

I tried

1. > `new_div.append(it)`
2. > ```
   > let len = it.length;
   >     for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   >         const element = it[i];
   >         console.log(i,' = ', element.value);
   >         new_div.appendChild(element);
   >     } //But this was not working
   > ```
3. > ```
   > new_div.appendChild(it[0]);
   > new_div.appendChild(it[1]); //Error message showed : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
   > ```
4. > ```
   > new_div.insertAdjacentHTML(it);
   > ```

Comment: it was better if you post your relevant html code, but I think trying `new_div.appendChild(it.children)` won't be a bad idea

Comment: I think you will get idea from this: <div class="check_box_div" style="padding: 10px 15px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin: 10px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between;"><input type="checkbox"><p class="para">dewf</p></div>

This is the div which I deleted, from there. 

By the way, it.children also not worked.

Comment: (Please do not use quote formatting in addition to code formatting. There is no proper reason to pretend this was a "quote".)

Comment: `node` is a "live NodeList", so when you remove the element from the DOM, the indexes all change.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. I got it. I stored its size in a variable and it works perfectly.

Comment: It's not just the size. When you remove `node[i]`, `node[i+1]` becomes `node[i]`. But then you increment `i`, and this skips the node that moved. The simplest solution is to convert the NodeList to an array.